# Adding multiple hidden fields using a single append statement

Tags: jquery, forms, append, hidden

```
 jQuery("#replymultiple").append(jQuery("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked"));
```

This is my code. Using this, I am appending some elements into my #replymultiple form. I want them to be hidden. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple function call:

```
jQuery("#replymultiple").append(jQuery("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked").attr("type", "hidden"));
```

Comment: for jquery 1.6+, you can also use .prop('type', 'hidden'). Its an advancement over .attr as type is a property of input element rather than attribute.

Comment: I know, but I think the "type" is more like a static attribute that really should be changed through .attr(). But that debates leads away from the question.

Comment: using .attr('type', 'hidden') dint work for me :( I ended up appending the elements to a div and the div was hidden as a whole.

Comment: Ok, I see, but then simply use .hide() instead of .attr("type", "hidden"), that should definitely work

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I want to hide the elements after calling `append`.

Maybe:

```
jQuery("#replymultiple").append(jQuery("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked"));

$("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']").hide();
```

or want input type hidden

```
jQuery("#replymultiple").append(jQuery("#tickets-expanded input:checkbox[name='ids[]']:checked").attr("type", "hidden"));
```

Comment: I will try using your first method. Thats something new. And as I said, specifying the type with .attr dint work out for me.